# checking whether device is connected to web

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an app which first checks if the device is connected to web or not.

If yes, then certain activity is started else other activity will start.

```
ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = ni.isConnected();

if (isConnected) {
    //connected, do something online.
} else {
    //Not connected.  
}
```

I have written the above code as an event when the particular button is pressed. But when i run it on the emulator and press that button, i'm getting a force close message.

**Note:** I have added the activities in the manifest file and also have declared following user-permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem and point in the right direction?

Comment: The user Permission is :  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Check the DDMS to see what kind of exception you are getting.

Comment: post your button click code also.

Comment: Check your logcat stack traces. Chances are that ni is null.

Comment: this is the code:                                                 public void handleClick(View v){                  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

boolean isConnected = ni.isConnected();

if(isConnected){

//connected, do something online.

} else{

//Not connected.

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
hello.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View paramView) {
        net = isOnline();
        Toast.makeText(SampleActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

private boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == State.CONNECTED ||
    connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == State.CONNECTED) {

} else {            

}
```

Comment: you have not accepted any answer, it would be great if you share your solution with us if you got anything from somewhere else.